# inverted pendulum REINFORCE

Tags: python, reinforcement-learning, policy-gradients

I am learning reinforcement learning, and as a practice, I am trying to stabilize an inverted pendulum  (gym: [Pendulum-v0](https://github.com/openai/gym/wiki/Pendulum-v0)) in an upright position using policy gradient: REINFORCE.

I have some questions, please help me, I tried a lot but couldn't understand. an answer to any question can help me. Thanks in advance.

1- why the observations in the pendulum [code](https://github.com/openai/gym/blob/master/gym/envs/classic_control/pendulum.py) are: cos(theta), sin(theta) and theta_dot? not theta and theta_dot only?

2- the action which I should send to the environment (env.step(action)) is it correct like this (in python):

```
prob=output.eval(arguments={observations: state})[0][0][0]  
# output of the neural network 

# Bernoulli dist. either 1 or 0 according to a threshold (rand.)
action = 1 if np.random.uniform() < prob else 0
```

3- the reward function is defined in the pendulum code as follows, but I couldn't understand why! shouldn't it be something like if the pendulum is upright (with some tolerance) so the reward is high, otherwise zero?

```
costs = angle_normalise((th)**2 +.1*thdot**2 + .001*(action**2))
# normalize between -pi and pi
reward=-costs
```

4- The pendulum motion equation is different from what is known (like [here](https://jeremykao.net/2017/07/03/simulating-a-simple-pendulum-in-python-part-1/)), the environment code use the following equation, where is comes from?

```
 newthdot = thdot + (-3*g/(2*l) * np.sin(th + np.pi) + 3./(m*l**2)*u) * dt
```

Comment: Re: 1, if you use theta, then you run into issues where there's a discontinuity when the angle wraps around from 2*pi to 0. If you use cosine and sine, these are continuous as the angle wraps, and knowing both enables you to compute theta.

Answer (score 0):

I know some of your questions.

First of all, I wrote a [REINFORCE code](https://github.com/rezakarbasi/Course_RL_S2021/blob/main/9-%20REINFORCE/PendulumREINFORCE.py) for this problem ( hyperparameters did not set properly). This [link](https://github.com/rezakarbasi/Course_RL_S2021/blob/main/9-%20REINFORCE/REINFORCE.ipynb) is for cartpole (by REINFORCE)

1. $cos(\theta)$ shows the height of the pendulum. $sin(\theta)$ shows how much to the left or right it is. But if you use $\theta$ itself, it encodes this information much more complicated. Maybe this kind of inputs rely on this point.
2. You can refer to the [link](https://github.com/rezakarbasi/Course_RL_S2021/blob/main/9-%20REINFORCE/PendulumREINFORCE.py) to make sure, but I think your action range is wrong:
   if you use `env = gym.make("Pendulum-v0")` to make your environment, then your action domain is between -2 and 2.
   You can find your action range by typing `print(env.action_space)`.  This print says you have one output and it's domain is between -2 and 2.
3. As I understand the reward from this [link](https://github.com/openai/gym/wiki/Pendulum-v0), this reward minimizes the following:

   $(\theta^2 + 0.1*(\frac{d\ \theta}{dt})^2 + 0.001*\text{action}^2)$

it has 3 terms:

1. $\theta^2$ : minimizing this is our main goal because getting $\theta$ to 0 means the pendulum go to the high up.
2. $(\frac{d\ \theta}{dt})^2$: minimizing this term means to be steady and do not move any more.
3. $\text{action}^2$: I think this term is for minimizing energy or sth.
4. I do not know that exactly but it seems that they simulate this by [state space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/State-space_representation) modeling.